# Why can't you group descendants in a CSS selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

If you want to assign the same style to a group of descendants, why isn't there an easy way to do this with CSS?

Say you have an HTML table as follows:

```
<table id='myTable'>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  .
  .
  .
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Why do you have to style all column headings and cells with the following selector?

```css
#myTable th, #myTable td {}
```

Why isn't there a syntax similar to the following?

```css
#myTable (th,td) {}
```

Comment: If you want that syntax you may extend your editor to automatically expand it to the standard-compliant form.

Answer (score 9):

> Why isn't there a syntax similar to the following?
>
> ```css
> #myTable (th,td) {}
> ```

Quite simply because nobody bothered to propose a useful syntax... until as recently (relative to the time you posted this anyway) as 2008, as an [`:any()` pseudo-class](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2008Oct/0066.html). This was discussed in greater depth [a little later](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2010Jan/0209.html).

The first implementation surfaced from Mozilla, albeit as late as 2010, in the guise of [`:-moz-any()`](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/05/moz-any-selector-grouping):

```css
#myTable :-moz-any(th, td) {}
```

The following year, [it would be suggested that WebKit follow suit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38095), with [`:-webkit-any()`](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/81742):

```css
#myTable :-webkit-any(th, td) {}
```

But if you were to try to use both prefixes together right now, then [due to selector parsing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317954/ignoring-webkit-specific-css-selector-in-firefox/8318202#8318202) you would have to *duplicate the rulesets*, making your code *even longer* and defeating the intended purpose of the pseudo-class:

```css
#myTable :-moz-any(th, td) {}
#myTable :-webkit-any(th, td) {}
```

Which makes using the prefixed selectors in public-facing code all but pointless. I can see no legitimate use for them anywhere other than vendor-specific code, which means you probably won't be using them together, in the same stylesheet.

The new Selectors level 4 working draft has a proposal for a [`:matches()` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#matches), which is based on the original `:any()` proposal but may see certain enhancements as the draft is revised:

```css
#myTable :matches(th, td) {}
```

Of course, since it's a new draft, don't expect browser support until much later.

In the very specific case of styling both `th` and `td` elements, you could use `*` instead assuming that none of the `tr` elements in this table will ever contain children other than cell elements, such as `script` or `template`:

```css
#myTable tr > * {}
```

But if you're a performance junkie and hate the `*` selector, you'll have to stick with doing it the long way.

Answer (score 2):

You can group selectors by using the vendor specific `-moz-any()` and `-webkit-any()`.

Please see the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3A-moz-any) on this, and the [W3C recommendation](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#matches) on the `:matches()` pseudo-attribute.

Cheers!

Comment: The latest W3C selectors recommendation is level 3, not 4. Selectors 4 just went into early drafts at the time you posted this.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into SASS - http://sass-lang.com

It allows you to write CSS in a more sensible way (similar to what you suggested), but ti still compiles down to plain old CSS.

For example:

```
#myTable{
    background: #CCC;

    tr{
      border: 1px solid #EEE;
    }

    td{
      background: blue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short of taking it up with the W3C, you could use jQuery for a similar sort of thing

```
$('#myTable').find('tr, td');
```

Of course, JS isn't always enabled and it would not be a good idea to rely on this. You're just going to have to list out all your selectors!

Comment: @alex - tx, I was wondering what the history/rationale was of precluding this type of thing in CSS

Comment: Probably just the W3C doing things a bit funny... they do that a bit.