# Is there a way to group CSS selectors for clarity?

Tags: css, css-selectors, syntactic-sugar

If I have a dozen CSS selectors, and want to assign `:hover` properties to all of them, I'm used to doing this:

```
selector, selector2, someOtherSelector, someSelector div {
    //some properties
}
selector:hover, selector2:hover, someOtherSelector:hover, someSelector div:hover {
    //some properties
}
```

Typing `:hover` four times seems redundant. Is there a way to group the selectors like

```
(selector, selector2, someOtherSelector, someSelector div):hover {
     //some properties
}
```

instead?

Comment: An interesting related question, btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800779/why-cant-you-group-descendants-in-a-css-selector?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they all share the same hover properties you could create a class that is shared for all that defines your :hover

So you'd get:

```
allSelectors, selector, selector2, someOtherSelector, someSelector div {
    //some properties
}
allSelectors:hover {
    //some properties
}
```

Re-usable classes makes for cleaner and less code.

Answer (score 5):

Not natively in CSS. By using something like [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/), you can write:

```
selector, selector2, someOtherSelector, someSelector div {
  // some properties

  &:hover {
    // some more properties
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, there's [not really](http://webdesign.about.com/od/cssselectors/qt/tipcssgroupsele.htm) any [easier way](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/grouping/) of doing what you're trying to do, unfortunately. Unless you want to move the styles to jQuery or something (but that's not a good solution).