# CSS Shorthand to identify multiple classes

Tags: css, regex, css-selectors

I read [this tutorial](http://webhole.net/2010/01/14/css-regular-expressions/) on using regular expressions with CSS selectors and am trying to extrapolate: Is there a CSS shorthand to do the following? I want to select all div's with class of "foo" that have either an additional class of "a", "b", "c", or "d".

```
    .foo.a,
    .foo.b,
    .foo.c,
    .foo.d {
       /* stuff */
    }
```

something like:

`.foo[class~='a','b','c','d'] {}` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible, currently (with the Selectors 3 recommendation). There isn't a full-fledged regex grammar for CSS, nor is there a way to crunch down parts of multiple selector lists.

Selectors 4 proposes a new [`:matches()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#matches) pseudo-class based on Mozilla's original `:any()` implementation (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800779/why-cant-you-group-descendants-in-a-css-selector/11786102#11786102) for a bit of history):

```
.foo:matches(.a, .b, .c, .d)
```

Of course, don't expect browser support for this yet. I might even forget to update this answer when that time comes but... we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `.foo[class~='a'][class~='b'][class~='c'][class~='d']` ?

Comment: No, that requires that the element has all 5 classes to be matched.

Comment: Yeah I suppose so. Anyway, pretty unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

No, your first way of writing it is the correct way. You can only search for one match at time with an attribute selector so the closest thing that's a mixture of your two methods is:

```
.foo[class~="a"],
.foo[class~="b"],
.foo[class~="c"],
.foo[class~="d"] {
   /* stuff */
}
```

Which really isn't shorthand or anything :P The best way to select by classes is just the ordinary way with a `.className`. Attribute selectors are only really helpful for selecting other attributes, or if you have a class that begins with a certain word and are using css3. For example you could use something like:

```
.foo[class^="mah-class"]{ }
```

Which would match `mah-class-a` `mah-class-b` `mah-classAHHH`... etc

Comment: You should probably be using `class~=` in your 2nd example. Using `class^=` means that the selector is picky about the order of CSS classes, so in the following HTML it would match the first, but not the 2nd. `<p class="mah-class foo">hi</p>
<p class="foo mah-class">there</p>`