# CSS3 combining selectors with OR instead of AND

Tags: css, css-selectors, logical-operators

Given this selector:

```
body[class*="page-node-add-"][class~="page-node-edit"] {background:red;}
```

It will match a body which has a class that contains a substring of *page-node-add-* AND a class which is exactly *page-node-edit*

I would like to say match the first OR the second (but not both). Is it possible?

**The problem with using a comma:**

If I have a long selector like:

```
body[class*="page-node-add-"] form.node-form > .field-type-field-collection > table > thead tr th,
body[class~="page-node-edit"] form.node-form > .field-type-field-collection > table > thead tr th
{...}
```

That is a pain I would have thought CSS3 would remedy that, I was imagining something like:

```
body([class*="page-node-add-"]):or([class~="page-node-edit"]) {background:red;}
```

Thanks

Comment: Seriously, you have to work on your style writing CSS, your selectors look (and most likely perform) horrible.

Comment: Thanks but I know how to write css very well and this is not how I would normally do it. I have a task to go into 1000s of lines of CMS produced markup in the admin area (so browser compatibility not an issue and try and colour code and collapse element etc with css and js so that it makes sense to the average website editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to split them up using a comma:

```
body[class*="page-node-add-"], body[class~="page-node-edit"] {background:red;}
```

**The problem with using a comma:**

... is that you can't do it any other way than with a comma. Perhaps it could have been remedied with Selectors 3, but unfortunately the spec says otherwise. That is only going to be remedied by [Selectors 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#matches), either because it wasn't proposed until recently, or it *was* proposed but didn't make the cut for level 3.

In level 4 of Selectors you will be able to do something like this:

```
body:matches([class*="page-node-add-"], [class~="page-node-edit"]) form.node-form > .field-type-field-collection > table > thead tr th
{...}
```

Currently, this is being implemented under its originally-proposed name, `:any()`, with the prefixes `:-moz-any()` and `:-webkit-any()`. But using `:any()` in public-facing CSS is pointless given that

1. only Gecko and WebKit support it; and
2. [you have to duplicate your rulesets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8318202/106224) because of the way prefixed selectors are handled, which not only defeats the intended purpose of the `:matches()` selector, but makes things even worse:

   ```
   body:-moz-any([class*="page-node-add-"], [class~="page-node-edit"]) form.node-form > .field-type-field-collection > table > thead tr th
   {...}
   body:-webkit-any([class*="page-node-add-"], [class~="page-node-edit"]) form.node-form > .field-type-field-collection > table > thead tr th
   {...}
   ```

In other words, until implementations update themselves to the standardized `:matches()`, there is no other viable solution (save from using a preprocessor to generate the repeated selectors for you).

Comment: Similar answer (whch I like a tad more as it links to another prior answer to this) is http://stackoverflow.com/a/10753421/2255628 (also on this page).

Comment: @Destiny Architect: I actually prefer this answer to the prior one as this one highlights the counter-productiveness of using the prefixes in production. But I should probably mark the questions as duplicates anyway. It's just a matter of which one should be the dupe target.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here:

[CSS Shorthand to identify multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893318/css-shorthand-to-identify-multiple-classes#answer-6893337)

Mozilla and webkit has a -moz-any or -webkit-any, though in the CSS4 spec there is a :matches. Suprised this wasn't thought of in CSS3 as it would greatly reduce the amount of repetative code without having to use SASS or LESS or whatever.

Comment: Yeah, but because of the prefixes you have to duplicate the rules. Applying that other answer of mine to what you have, you can see that it doesn't really help matters...

Comment: Similar answer is http://stackoverflow.com/a/10753216/2255628 (also on this page).  ‘matches’ good description at https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/m/matches/ but currently not in http://caniuse.com/#search=matches as https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-matchesselectors is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

So you really want `XOR` when I read your question.
You can achive this by using the `:not` selector and say "class one and not the other" and the other way around.

```
div.one:not(.two), div.two:not(.one) {
    background:red;
}
```

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/XfgxK/3/

Comment: That's exactly what he wants as far as I understood the question right.

Comment: Once you replace those classes with the given attributes or the full complex selectors, this gets crazy long. Again, there's no viable workaround for it yet.

Comment: @BoltClock Nope, OP is asking for xor.

Comment: Well, this is pretty confusing. The OP found another answer of mine which says exactly the same thing and he calls it "the answer", but after a second read it does seem like he's asking for XOR, not OR.

Comment: Also, unless you have other classes to filter by, you don't necessarily have to say `div.one:not(.two)`, you can simply say `div:not(.two)`. See http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/XfgxK/4/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css/10711731#10711731

Comment: Yep, but you've to be aware that this is another scenario since you're matching former unrelated div's now. http://jsfiddle.net/TyYJ5/1/ Which is not the case when using the former code: http://jsfiddle.net/XfgxK/5/