# Applying css on the head and the body of my table in 1 single line

Tags: css, css-selectors

With the following css I define the 1st col of the head of my table

```
table.search-transport tr th:nth-child(1) { width: 30px; text-align:right; }
```

I would like to apply this css not only on the head but also on the body of the table.

I know we can proceed in 2 lines:

```
table.search-transport tr th:nth-child(1),
table.search-transport tr td:nth-child(1)
                  { width: 30px; text-align:right; }
```

But I would like to know if we can proceed in 1 signe line? Something like:

```
table.search-transport tr th:nth-child(1) + td:nth-child(1) { width: 30px; text-align:right; }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it's any cell in the first column? You should be able to simply omit the `th`/`td` part altogether, as well as making use of the child selector since a `tr` can only have either a `th` or a `td` as a child (and you want to ensure you only select its child and not any inner elements):

```
table.search-transport tr > :nth-child(1) { width: 30px; text-align: right; }
```

(If you want to support older browsers replace `:nth-child(1)` with `:first-child`.)

Generally speaking, though, you can't choose both `th:nth-child(1)` and `td:nth-child(1)` separately while avoiding duplicating the rest of the selector. This has been covered to death elsewhere on the site already, but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800779/why-cant-you-group-descendants-in-a-css-selector/11786102#11786102) for a little extra info.

Comment: The problem with the solution you suggest is that I have a label in this 1st cell and this label is also affected.

Comment: Really don't understand, I posted the same answer moments after you posted your question. This guy after making zillion edits posts the same answer as mine and you accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector which you are using currently is poor in terms of performance.

Following line answers your question.

```
.search-transport tr > :nth-child(1) { width: 30px; text-align: right; }
```

Check the fiddle to see selector in action http://jsfiddle.net/LNJLf/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for the `:any` pseudoclass. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:any.

```
table.search-transport tr :any(th,td):nth-child(1) { width: 30px; text-align:right; }
```

Note: you'll need to vendor prefix this. Untested.

Comment: Not only will you need to prefix this, but you have to repeat the *entire rule* as many times as is necessary depending on how many browsers use the prefix (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753174/css3-combining-selectors-with-or-instead-of-and/10753216#10753216) for example), which makes it even worse than what's already in the question. In other words, it's counterproductive, and useless in its current form.

Comment: Also, the unprefixed version is specced as [`:matches()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#matches) instead.