# Some selectors doesn't work for me

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I was writing some selectors but it didn't work for me.

**HTML code :**

```
<h2 rel="singer-connector-cricketer">Shoaib Chikate</h2>
<h2 rel="dancer-build-tester">Ashok Dongare</h2>
```

**CSS code:**

```
h2[rel|="connector"]{
    color:blue;
}
```

[**CSS Tricks Attribute**](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/)

Similarly another :matches() selector is also not working although I'm using higher version of chrome (Version 32.0.1700.77).

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="matcher">
        <p>Matched</p>
        <h1>Not</h1>
        <h2>Matched</h2>
        <h3>Not</h3>
</div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
#matcher :matches(p,h2){
    color:purple;
}
```

How this selectors will work?

[**CSS tricks Selectors- :matches()**](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/m/matches/)

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/shoaibista/CUvZ8/)

Comment: What's the exact version of Chrome you're using? Please don't just say "higher version". If you're using Canary, say so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`h2[rel|="connector"]` looks for an attribute value that *starts* with "connector" followed by a hyphen. It does not look for an attribute value that has the word "connector" anywhere among a set of hyphenated words — the value must *start* with the given string.

Since the two elements given have `rel` attributes whose values start with "singer-" and "dancer-" respectively, neither of them will be matched.

I'm not aware of any version of Chrome that supports `:matches()` yet. The latest stable version (34.x as of this writing) does still support `:-webkit-any()`, however.

Of course, it should go without saying that you shouldn't use `:-webkit-any()` and the rest of the prefixes in production code, because CSS error handling rules mean that using it in its current prefixed state actually causes you to have to write duplicate rules for each prefix, which runs completely counter to its intended purpose. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753174/css3-combining-selectors-with-or-instead-of-and/10753216#10753216) for an example. You can test these new selectors all you want, but there's very little to gain from trying to use them in production while support for them is still poor.

Comment: starts with is `^=`. `|=` is a word contained in the attribute

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan: No, `|=` has a "starts-with" restriction as well. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#matching-attrs and http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation

Comment: Oh, You're absolutely right "*...or beginning with "val"...*" I never noticed this behaviour. That's why I like SO, There's always something new to learn.

Comment: |= checks for '-' as seperator so your answer doesn't provide me solution.

Comment: @Shoaib Chikate: You never said anything about a solution - in fact, looking at your question again, you haven't actually asked anything, so it should have been closed instead of answered.

Comment: Yes makes sense, I just want this selectors to work and in my question I said some selectors are not working and ask why they are not??

Comment: @Shoaib Chikate: Just saw your comment on Julian's answer. So, I'm confused - are you looking for an explanation or a solution?

Comment: I got the solution. Explaination is fine. I was confuse when I saw the first answer. Its fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I would try using `#matcher :-moz-any(p,h2)` and `#matcher :-webkit-any(p,h2)` instead of `:matches` cause there are only a few browsers supporting `:matches` at the moment.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/CUvZ8/2/

Comment: But the another selector h2[rel*="connector"] is not solution because my question is why the selector which I have used it is not working.