# Is there a shortcut for CSS state selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a more compact way of writing this for example?

```
.behind a.delete-btn, 
.behind a.delete-btn:active, 
.behind a.delete-btn:visited, 
.behind a.delete-btn:focus, 
.behind a.delete-btn:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Depends. If you're not trying to override previous `:active`, `:visited`, `:focus`, or `:hover` styles, you can eliminate those and let them inherit the `a.delete-btn` styles.

Comment: ah good point, i am trying to override existing styles

Comment: Then aside from using `!important`, you really don't have any shortcuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there isn't a shortcut syntax for this.

Selectors 4 will provide a `:matches()` pseudo-class that essentially provides this shortcut syntax, but the only implementations exist as prefixed `:any()`, which are reserved for internal use and testing purposes. Plus, due to parsing rules, [trying to use `:any()` in its prefixed state would require repeating everything anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753174/css3-combining-selectors-with-or-instead-of-and/10753216#10753216), so you're better off waiting until browsers start implementing the standardized `:matches()`.

Meanwhile, if you're trying to override existing styles on `a` elements for all states, and `.behind a.delete-btn` by itself is not specific enough, you can cheat by doubling one of the classes (since a class selector and a pseudo-class have the same specificity):

```
.behind a.delete-btn.delete-btn {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

If this is too hacky for you, then there's no other way than to specify all its state pseudo-classes again as you have done.