# Is there a way to shorten css selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have:

```
#signUpForm h1, #signUpForm p{
    color: #fff;
}
```

Is there a way to shorten this such as:

```
#signUpForm h1, p{
    color: #fff;
}
```

Or do I need to create a new comma separated selector each time, as in my first example?

Comment: Maybe just `#signUpForm { color: #fff; }` will fit to what you need ?

Comment: I agree with Singe on that. You're changing only the text color, and the child container will inherit the parent container's color.

Comment: Yes, in the simplified example above, it would, but in my real project I need to target individual elements.

Comment: Well I don't think you can do a shorter selector than your first one

Comment: I'm afraid there's no other way to simplify your selector any further but to assign identifiers or classes to the HTML elements themselves.

Comment: Ok, not a big deal. Just thought I'd ask because I was curious. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you could add for example the class="colorForm" and define it to #fff in CSS but the problem is deported to the HTML which is not too good

Comment: [You will be able to do](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#matches) `#signUpForm :matches(h1, p)` one day, but not yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the properties you are specifying and the elements you want to target, if its jut about `color` then you can write

```
#signUpForm {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Because `color` property will be inherited by `h1` as well as `p` but think of a scenario where you want to apply `font-weight` so here you cannot use the above selector as `font-weight` won't be inherited by `h1` tag.

If you want, you can use CSS pre processors like LESS or SASS where you can write like

```
#signUpForm {
    h1, p {
       font-weight: 100;
    }
}
```

But again, as I said, it depends on the properties you are writing, because some are inherited by the child elements and some are not, so even if you use `color` like

```
#signUpForm {
    h1, p {
       color: #fff;
    }
}
```

Makes no sense because that is equivalent to `#signUpForm { color: #fff; }` unless you've specified a different `color` for `h1` or `p`

Comment: Yeah LESS and SASS might be my next thing to check out. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Have you thought of using Sass, you could do something like

```
#signUpForm{ 
    h1, p {
        color: #fff;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:any`.

```
#signUpForm :any(h1,p) { }
```

Browser support varies. You may need to do `-webkit-any` etc.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:any. See also the proposal for the similar `:matches` CSS4 pseudo-class at http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#matches.

Comment: Good idea, but you're right about browser support. Thanks!

Comment: note that using pseudo also affects the specificity of your selectors

Comment: Using `:any()` is pointless due to the prefixes - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753174/css3-combining-selectors-with-or-instead-of-and/10753216#10753216 Also, it's a pseudo-class, not a pseudo-element.

Comment: @Mr. Alien: It shouldn't - the specificity of `:matches()` is whatever selector matches the element. The pseudo-class is not counted, similar to `:not()`.

Comment: http://the-echoplex.net/csscrush/ supports `:any`. You could use it until the browser support is better, without drinking all the LESS/SASS Kool-aid.