# Any - better - ideas on how to add underlines on links in Bootstrap 3 CSS then remove them?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

One of my pet peeves is no underlines on links in body text. I wish there was a way in customizer (on GetBootstrap.com) to just exclude components from getting underlined, but the rest is underlined. Or a prefix that can be targeted. In Bootstrap, if I am not touching the css, I'm usually doing the following in another style sheet.

**Any better ideas?**

```
/* ---- everything has an underline by default */
a {
  text-decoration:underline; 
}

/* ---- removing underlines on bootstrap components */
a.btn,
.nav a:not(:hover),
.navbar a:not(:hover),
.pagination a:not(:hover),
.pager a:not(:hover),
.list-group a:not(:hover),
.breadcrumb a:not(:hover) {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.nav a:hover,
.navbar a:hover,
.list-group a:hover,
.breadcrumb a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with using simply `a` selector instead of `a:not(:hover)`? Then overriding text declaration for `:hover` pseudo class?

Comment: @HashemQolami  Now I see why I have that the way I do. All links in bootstrap are not underlined, but when they hover they are underlined, that's why I have it that way. I am just putting back the default behavior. I'm thinking I'll just add a custom class on any bootstrap component, that might be less messy.

Comment: @HashemQolami Ahhh, yes that will do the trick and shorten the css

Comment: @Christina I meant targeting `.nav a, .navbar a, ...` and so on not the all `a` elements. You might also want to [group the selectors by `:any()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285518/how-to-target-a-group-of-long-similar-css-selectors-on-one-line/25286385#25286385) pseudo class, but it's worth noting that it's an experimental technology, and W3C standard `:matches()` selector is not supported in any web browser. *(deleted the previous comment to correct typos)*