# Targeting Same Children, but only Certain, Differing Parents -- CSS and jQuery Selector Style

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Is there a way to target only certain children of select parents without duplicating the children selectors and making the selector go off the charts in terms of length?

For example, I want to select the first-child paragraph of certain divs.

CSS would be like

```
.funny > p:first-child, .sad > p:first-child {
 color: red
}
```

The markup

```
<div class="funny">
  <p>This is red</p>
  <p>This is whatever</p>
  <p>This is whatever</p>
  <p>This is whatever</p>
</div>

<div class="wildcrazy">
  <p>This is whatever</p>
  <p>This is whatever</p>
  <p>This is whatever</p>
  <p>This is whatever</p>
</div>

<div class="sad">
  <p>This is red</p>
  <p>This is whatever</p>
  <p>This is whatever</p>
  <p>This is whatever</p>
</div>
```

Obviously, there could be loads of other first paragraphs in lots of other divs besides funny and sad that I *do* want to target, and there could also be loads of other divs like wildcrazy that I *do not* want to target.

My question is: can I some how declare the child and prepend it with all the parents?  Something like:

`.funny, .sad, .another_div_class0, .another_div_class1, .another_div_class2, .another_div_class3 > p:first-child`

instead of

`.funny p:first, .sad p:first-child, .another_div_class0 p:first-child, .another_div_class1 p:first-child, .another_div_class2 p:first-child, .another_div_class3 p:first-child`

Comment: No, you can't do that. You have to define *all* parents with children you want to be affected

Comment: Yeah, I am figuring that's the way, Zoltan... don't want to use jQuery .has(), either.

Comment: you should also avoid using child selectors in jQuery - it adds a LOT of overhead - that's one of the reasons why jQuery included the .children(), .first() and .parent() (and other related) selectors in their library

Comment: Similar but not the same: [CSS shorthand to identify multiple classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893318/css-shorthand-to-identify-multiple-classes) There are a number of other questions which do ask the same thing, but they are very poorly-worded so it's pretty difficult to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @BoltClock: Thanks for the reference to that other question.  Thoroughly rounds out the no-can-do status of this query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in jquery this:

```
.funny, .sad, .another_div_class0, .another_div_class1, .another_div_class2, .another_div_class3 > p:first
```

would translate to this:

```
$('.funny, .sad, .another_div_class0, .another_div_class1, .another_div_class2, .another_div_class3').children('p:first')
```

Comment: This worked as long as i used .find(). .children() just hit the first  http://jsfiddle.net/7rMw5/

Comment: `:first` is not the same as `:first-child`, which is why you're seeing different results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know with CSS, but you could do it with jquery. Put all your parent classes in a selector, then state you only want a p if it's a child of the selector:

```
$('.funny, .sad, .another_div_class0, .another_div_class1, .another_div_class2, .another_div_class3').each( function() {
    $('p:first-child', this).css(Do whatever you want);
});
```

Comment: yeah.. this is closest in the world of jQuery, but it's using .each(), which is fine... but I just wondered if it could be done with selectors only.  Thanks, Michael...

Comment: Yeah, no worries. And there's probably a cleaner way without the .each()

Answer (score 0):

why not add another class to the `div`'s you want to select like this

```
<div class="funny selectthis">
  <p>This is red</p>
  <p>This is whatever</p>
  <p>This is whatever</p>
  <p>This is whatever</p>
</div>

<div class="wildcrazy">
  <p>This is whatever</p>
  <p>This is whatever</p>
  <p>This is whatever</p>
  <p>This is whatever</p>
</div>

<div class="sad selectthis">
  <p>This is red</p>
  <p>This is whatever</p>
  <p>This is whatever</p>
  <p>This is whatever</p>
</div>
```

Then just use this

```
$('.selectthis').find('p:first').css('color','red');​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U6qhb/

Comment: I can't change the HTML structure.  Class nameis based on a Django slug

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.funny, .sad, .another_div_class0, .another_div_class1, .another_div_class2, .another_div_class3').find('p:first')
```