# Why is font-family not properly cascading in this button?

Tags: css, fonts

Here is the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/LDEt6/

The first CSS rule sets the font-family as `'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;` and all other font settings in the CSS below simply state 'inherit'.. in Chrome 21 however I am getting "Times" as the computed font-family and in Firefox I am getting 'serif'. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, `initial` is supposed to exist on its own, just like `inherit`, so you can't have `initial initial` for your background properties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First we have:

```
body {
     font-family : 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Cool, thats fine. But then we have:

```
html, body, input, button, <snipped...> {
     font: inherit;
}
```

So `font` get overwritten by this rule which also applies to body, it is now `inherit`.

So what does inherit do? It says "use the styling property assigned to my parent element". In this case, the parent of `<body>` element is `<html>` which has no parent. So no specified font family at all at the root, so nothing can inherit.

What `inherit` does not do, is use the previously defined value for *that element*. It inherits from the parents, not the previous style that would have applied. `inherit` is about HTML structure, not CSS structure.

In the end, you set the entire universe to inherit a font from its parent, including all parents. So you never actually find a parent with a real set font. Instead the browser applies its default font, just so it can render *something*.

If you move your `body` font rule after to giant reset rule there, it should start working. Fonts will then inherit all the way up to the body tag, which has a real font now.

Comment: And the problem with CSS resets is that they're designed to screw up inheritance.

Comment: Also, the reason why IE and Opera appear to display Helvetica Neue properly is because of the `button::-moz-focus-inner` selector at the very end of the rule, which causes them to ignore **the entire rule** as per the spec, completely preventing the override from happening for any element. The reason why Chrome applies the override anyway is because [WebKit deliberately violates the spec by isolating unrecognized prefixes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728360/why-can-i-not-group-browser-specific-css-selectors-for-different-browsers?lq=1#comment13940630_10728507).

Comment: @BoltClock: took me embarassingly long to adopt [normalize](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) to avoid inheritance screw-ups

Comment: When you specify `font: inherit` on the `html` element, it takes after the user-defined preferences. Then, naturally, anything inheriting from `html` will follow suit.

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/LDEt6/6/

In the large clump of selectors you redeclare the `body` as `font: inherit`.

Comment: OP's question was why the `input, button` selector isn't inheriting from `body`.