# Weird CSS bug in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I have wrapped an input slider and two overlay boxes into a div container. I have fitted everything and it is looking fine so far. Nevertheless, I am experiencing a weird offsetting bug in Firefox and it is driving me nuts. Firefox seems to always offset the input slider to the right. I have colored the input slider in purple to show this offset more clearly. How can I prevent this?

You can view the current version here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDLTQ/24/
The corresponding div wrapper is named `.slider_wrapper` and the input slider `#range`.
Is there anything that I am not considering?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the

```
input[type=range],
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb
```

css rule

when using vendor specific selectors (*not properties*) they have to be on their own (*or other same-vendor selectors*).

Otherwise the parsing engine considers the selector wrong and ignores the whole rule..
(*see [Why isn't it possible to combine vendor-specific pseudo-elements/classes into one rule set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982449/why-isnt-it-possible-to-combine-vendor-specific-pseudo-elements-classes-into-on) for more*)

---

Try with

```
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  margin:0; padding:0; border:0;
  }

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  margin:0; padding:0; border:0;
}
```

Comment: not when considered wrong . but when not recognized it ignores all rule

Comment: Wow, indeed! This fixed it. Thanks for the reply and the reference.