# Can't combine selectors using commas in CSS

Tags: html, css

HTML5 placeholders always appear slightly higher than the center of the input, so I'm trying to use CSS like `::-webkit-input-placeholder` to push them down a bit. For some reason, I can't combine the selectors. Here's a Fiddle demonstrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/n7VV7/

I don't want to separate them because I use a CSS compression tool that automatically combines lines. Right now, I can manually separate them, but in the future, I will forget that I can't combine these lines.

Comment: A question should contain code for reproducing the issue, in the question itself. Moreover, it should state the desired goal, rather than name an attempted solution (like “combine selectors using commas”, which cannot be done, since commas are sepatators between selectors, not combiners).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use commas to combine vendor-prefixed selectors because when a browser encounters a selector it does not understand, that line is "thrown out." This is why it's necessary to break up vendor prefixes for *any* selector, not just the `::` pseudo-classes.

Here's a link to a [CSS-Tricks article](https://web.archive.org/web/20230518144900/https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/) that mentions the problem:

> Note that while we’re repeating code here, that’s necessary as you can’t comma-separate these type of selectors. Browsers will drop the entire selector if it doesn’t understand a part of it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is impossible to combine them in one selector, because `input-placeholder` selectors are used only separately and it is described in a standard.

There is a similar question around: [Why isn't it possible to combine vendor-specific pseudo-elements/classes into one rule set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982449/why-isnt-it-possible-to-combine-vendor-specific-pseudo-elements-classes-into-on)