# On Edge Browser, how to change input placeholder text color using CSS?

Tags: html, css, placeholder, microsoft-edge

On Edge Browser, I couldn't able to change input placeholder color.

`:-ms-input-placeholder` is not working but works fine on `IE 10` & `IE 11`.

```
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-style:italic;        
    color: red;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

is there anyway to make it work using CSS?

Comment: Have you tried the `-webkit` version I think that mightbe a fallback for IE-Edge?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Didn't worked.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

From [**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder)

> ::-webkit-input-placeholder for (Chrome/Safari/Opera)
>
> :-ms-input-placeholder for IE.
>
> ::-ms-input-placeholder for Edge (also supports webkit prefix)

*Note the double colon syntax*

Comment: For my part it finaly worked on edge using input::-ms-input-placeholder{color: myColor;} . But it did not with input::-ms-input-placeholder, input:-ms-input-placeholder{color:myColor;}

Answer (score 15):

I want to second @ken's comment on @Paulie_D's answer, above.

This works:
`input[type="text"]::-ms-input-placeholder { color: #000; }`

This doesn't:
`input[type="text"]::placeholder, input[type="text"]::-ms-input-placeholder { color: #000; }`

I'm not sure why, but it definitely appears that the -ms-input-placeholder pseudo-element only works if it's separate from other directives.

Comment: Edge doesn't consinder ::placeholder a valid CSS and drops the entire rule. So even if you put there valid class say `.text-white, input[type="text"]::placeholder` the .text-white would have no rules applied to it for Edge while it would for all other browsers. It's something that can break sites in Edge.

Comment: That's fascinating- thanks for the clarification. Is this also how IE <=11 operate?

Comment: It is how most browsers operate. See: [Why isn't it possible to combine vendor-specific pseudo-elements/classes into one rule set?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16982449/501771)

Answer (score 8):

For the current version of the Microsoft Edge browser, placeholder doesn't work correctly. Take a look this issue [Microsoft Edge placeholder bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1627778/microsoft-edge-placeholder-bug). If placeholder is invisible, try to remove `position: relative` and `:-webkit-input-placeholder` opacity.

Comment: Crazy bug... still present

Comment: `transform: scale(1)` on the input itfself worked better for me. Placeholder reappeared like magic...