# CSS :after with ::after not work in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I know IE8 only supports `:after` and not `::after`.

I thought I could solve it in one line.

Here is the CSS:

```
E:after, E::after{ ..... }
```

But it doesn't work in IE8.

Comment: CSS code is no any error.

Answer (score 4):

IE8 is behaving as expected and discarding the entire ruleset *because* it doesn't recognize double colons. See [this slightly related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982449/why-isnt-it-possible-to-combine-vendor-specific-pseudo-elements-classes-into-on/16982510#16982510). This is not buggy behavior.

If you need to support IE8, just use single colons. That's what you're supposed to do. `:before` with a single colon is [guaranteed to work on all browsers and you can rely on it](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements) thanks to IE8.

```
E:after { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can place code for IE8 as this.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<style>...</style>
<![endif]-->
```