# Chain CSS Pseudo Selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I got this:

```
::selection {
    background-color: #80b3ff;
    color: #000000;
}
::-moz-selection {
    background-color: #80b3ff;
    color: #000000;
}
::-o-selection ....
```

But when I try to define all selectors together it doesn't work.

```
::selection, ::-moz-selection, ::-o-selection, ::-webkit-selection {
    background-color: #80b3ff;
    color: #000000;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't chain these element specific selectors. Same goes for `:fullscreen` or the components of a range input

Comment: FYI, ::-o-selection and ::-webkit-selection don't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `::selection` is a pseudo element. [There's a good explanation for this here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16982449/720238).

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find an answer. seems to be a duplicate :/ edit: linked it.