# Chaining pseudo selectors on :host

Tags: css

Is it possible to chain a pseudo selector like `:focus-within` onto `:host`?

I've seen this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42014015/chain-css-pseudo-selectors), but `:host` is a pseudo class and not a vendor specific selector / pseudo element.

Comment: did you try `:host(:focus-within)` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted.