# error on math game made with js and jquery? infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am making a math game but i am stuck, the game should be like this, first a + if the answer of input is equal to the + then another operator with other number will show, this will be the -, and the same process, then go the * and then restart again + - *, but my script its stuck on - every time and i dont see why here a [jsdfile](https://jsfiddle.net/vqemjoma/) (the styles are a little broken here)

and the code

```
var puntos = 0;
randomiseiconscycle1();

function randomiseiconscycle1() {
  $("#buttonstart").click(function() {
    $("#buttonstart").css("display", "none")
    $("#why").css("display", "none")
    $(".ahke").css("margin", "0")
    $("#atr").css("margin", "0")
    $(".f1").css("display", "none")
    $("#mathbox").show("slide", 1000);
  });
  var minNumber = 0;
  var maxNumber = 20;
  var randomNumber = 0;
  var randomNumber2 = 0;
  randomNumber = randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);
  randomNumber2 = randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);

  function randomNumberFromRange(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }
  $("#num1").text(randomNumber);
  $("#operador").text("+");
  $("#num2").text(randomNumber2);
  var resultado = randomNumber + randomNumber2;
  $("#resultado").on("input", function() {
    var input = $('#resultado').val();
    if (input == resultado) {
      input = $('#resultado').val("");
      minNumber = 1;
      puntos += 1;
      maxNumber = 15;
      randomNumber = 0;
      randomNumber2 = 0;
      randomNumber = randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);
      randomNumber2 = randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);
      $("#num1").text(randomNumber);
      $("#operador").text("-");
      $("#num2").text(randomNumber2);
      resultado = randomNumber - randomNumber2;

      if (input == resultado) {
        console.log("resta0");
        input = $('#resultado').val("");
        minNumber = 1;
        maxNumber = 8;
        puntos += 1;
        randomNumber = 0;
        randomNumber2 = 0;
        randomNumber = randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);
        randomNumber2 = randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);
        $("#num1").text(randomNumber);
        $("#num2").text(randomNumber2);
        $("#operador").text("*");
        resultado = randomNumber * randomNumber2;

        if (input == resultado) {
          puntos += 1;
          randomNumber = 0;
          randomNumber2 = 0;
          input = $('#resultado').val("");
          randomiseiconscycle1();
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

and sometimes autopass the if without the correct answer?

Comment: Typically folks that post questions, at the very least, acknowledge that people tried to help them.

Answer (score 0):

After each time you enter something in the input box, the "on input" fires.  It evaluates the first:

`if (input == resultado) {`

when it matches that (evaluates to true), you change resultado:

`resultado = randomNumber - randomNumber2;`

So your second (third, fourth,...) `if (input == resultado) {` evaluates to false, and you essentially start over at the top.

UPDATED with solution to go with answer:

```
var ops = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
var idx = 1;
$("#resultado").on("input", function() {
    var input = $('#resultado').val();
    if (input == resultado) {
        switch(idx) {
        case 0:
           //move your + here
           break;
        case 1:
           input = $('#resultado').val("");
           minNumber = 1;
           puntos += 1;
           maxNumber = 15;
           randomNumber= 0;
           randomNumber2= 0;
           randomNumber = randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);
           randomNumber2 = randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);
           $("#num1").text(randomNumber);
           $("#operador").text(ops[idx++]);
           $("#num2").text(randomNumber2);
           resultado = randomNumber - randomNumber2;
           break;
        case 2:
            console.log("resta0");
            input = $('#resultado').val("");
            minNumber = 1;
            maxNumber = 8;
            puntos += 1;
            randomNumber= 0;
            randomNumber2= 0;
            randomNumber = randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);
            randomNumber2 = randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);
            $("#num1").text(randomNumber);
            $("#num2").text(randomNumber2);
            $("#operador").text(ops[idx++]);
            resultado = randomNumber * randomNumber2;
           break;
        case 3:
           puntos += 1;
           randomNumber= 0;
           randomNumber2= 0;
           input = $('#resultado').val("");
           randomiseiconscycle1();
           break;
        default:
           //do something else
        }
    }
```

Note: I tried to leave your code as written, so you would recognize it.  I would very much recommend moving the resetting/reassignment of values to separate functions.

Answer (score 0):

You're only changing to `*` when the input is equal to the subtraction of the new problem you just displayed. But `input` still contains the user's answer to the *previous* problem. So this will only be true if the new problem has the same answer as the previous one.

Doing this as nested `if` statements is the wrong way, because you're doing the second `if` before the user has had a chance to respond to the new problem. You should use a different way to cycle through the operators, such as an array. Use a global variable to keep your current position in the array.

```js
var puntos = 0;
randomiseiconscycle1();

function randomiseiconscycle1() {
  var operators = [{
      char: '+',
      func: (x, y) => x + y,
      min: 0,
      max: 20
    },
    {
      char: '-',
      func: (x, y) => x - y,
      min: 1,
      max: 15
    },
    {
      char: '*',
      func: (x, y) => x * y,
      min: 1,
      max: 8
    }
  ];
  var opindex = -1;
  $("#buttonstart").click(function() {
    $("#buttonstart").css("display", "none")
    $("#why").css("display", "none")
    $(".ahke").css("margin", "0")
    $("#atr").css("margin", "0")
    $(".f1").css("display", "none")
    $("#mathbox").show();
  });

  var resultado;


  function randomNumberFromRange(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }

  function showProblem() {
    opindex = (opindex + 1) % operators.length;
    var randomNumber = randomNumberFromRange(operators[opindex].min, operators[opindex].max);
    var randomNumber2 = randomNumberFromRange(operators[opindex].min, operators[opindex].max);
    $("#num1").text(randomNumber);
    $("#operador").text(operators[opindex].char);
    $("#num2").text(randomNumber2);
    resultado = operators[opindex].func(randomNumber, randomNumber2);
    $("#resultado").val("");
  }
  showProblem();
  $("#resultado").on("input", function() {
    var input = $('#resultado').val();
    if (input == resultado) {
      puntos += 1;
      showProblem();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/*! HTML5 Boilerplate v6.1.0 | MIT License | https://html5boilerplate.com/ */


/*
 * What follows is the result of much research on cross-browser styling.
 * Credit left inline and big thanks to Nicolas Gallagher, Jonathan Neal,
 * Kroc Camen, and the H5BP dev community and team.
 */


/* ==========================================================================
   Base styles: opinionated defaults
   ========================================================================== */

html {
  color: #222;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.4;
}


/*
 * Remove text-shadow in selection highlight:
 * https://twitter.com/miketaylr/status/12228805301
 *
 * Vendor-prefixed and regular ::selection selectors cannot be combined:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/16982510/7133471
 *
 * Customize the background color to match your design.
 */

::-moz-selection {
  background: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
  background: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}


/*
 * A better looking default horizontal rule
 */

hr {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*
 * Remove the gap between audio, canvas, iframes,
 * images, videos and the bottom of their containers:
 * https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/440
 */

audio,
canvas,
iframe,
img,
svg,
video {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/*
 * Remove default fieldset styles.
 */

fieldset {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*
 * Allow only vertical resizing of textareas.
 */

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}


/* ==========================================================================
   Browser Upgrade Prompt
   ========================================================================== */

.browserupgrade {
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0.2em 0;
}


/* ==========================================================================
   Author's custom styles
   ========================================================================== */


/* ==========================================================================
   Helper classes
   ========================================================================== */


/*
 * Hide visually and from screen readers
 */

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}


/*
 * Hide only visually, but have it available for screen readers:
 * https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/hiding-content-for-accessibility
 *
 * 1. For long content, line feeds are not interpreted as spaces and small width
 *    causes content to wrap 1 word per line:
 *    https://medium.com/@jessebeach/beware-smushed-off-screen-accessible-text-5952a4c2cbfe
 */

.visuallyhidden {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* 1 */
}


/*
 * Extends the .visuallyhidden class to allow the element
 * to be focusable when navigated to via the keyboard:
 * https://www.drupal.org/node/897638
 */

.visuallyhidden.focusable:active,
.visuallyhidden.focusable:focus {
  clip: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  position: static;
  width: auto;
  white-space: inherit;
}


/*
 * Hide visually and from screen readers, but maintain layout
 */

.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}


/*
 * Clearfix: contain floats
 *
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    `contenteditable` attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that receive the `clearfix` class.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  /* 1 */
  display: table;
  /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}


/* ==========================================================================
   EXAMPLE Media Queries for Responsive Design.
   These examples override the primary ('mobile first') styles.
   Modify as content requires.
   ========================================================================== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {
  /* Style adjustments for viewports that meet the condition */
}

@media print,
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
(min-resolution: 1.25dppx),
(min-resolution: 120dpi) {
  /* Style adjustments for high resolution devices */
}


/* ==========================================================================
   Print styles.
   Inlined to avoid the additional HTTP request:
   https://www.phpied.com/delay-loading-your-print-css/
   ========================================================================== */

@media print {
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    background: transparent !important;
    color: #000 !important;
    /* Black prints faster */
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
  }
  a,
  a:visited {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  a[href]:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ")";
  }
  abbr[title]:after {
    content: " (" attr(title) ")";
  }
  /*
     * Don't show links that are fragment identifiers,
     * or use the `javascript:` pseudo protocol
     */
  a[href^="#"]:after,
  a[href^="javascript:"]:after {
    content: "";
  }
  pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap !important;
  }
  pre,
  blockquote {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
  /*
     * Printing Tables:
     * http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Printing_Tables
     */
  thead {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
  tr,
  img {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
  p,
  h2,
  h3 {
    orphans: 3;
    widows: 3;
  }
  h2,
  h3 {
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }
}

.f1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
  text-shadow: 3px 4px 2px rgb(150, 150, 150);
}

#g1 {
  margin-top: 3%
}

#atr {
  margin-top: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#why:hover {
  background-color: #9c43ccdb;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in;
  color: #ffffffeb;
}

#why {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
  padding: 0 5%;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 1px #2e134dc9, 0px 1px 1px #7a34cac9, 2px 1px 1px #2e134dc9, 1px 2px 1px #7a34cac9, 3px 2px 1px #2e134dc9, 2px 3px 1px #7a34cac9, 4px 3px 1px #2e134dc9, 3px 4px 1px #7a34cac9, 5px 4px 1px #2e134dc9, 4px 5px 1px #7a34cac9, 6px 5px 1px #2e134dc9;
  background-color: #7a34cac9;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#g3 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#g2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

#g4 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  animation: mymove 5s forwards;
}


/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */


/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

#tittle {
  position: relative;
  top: 4%;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 3px 4px 2px #00000082;
}

#tittle3 {
  position: relative;
  top: 2%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 5%;
  text-shadow: none;
}

#background {
  background-color: #2D97CB;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#tittle2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 4%;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 3px 4px 2px #00000082;
  margin-top: 0%;
}

.why2 {
  background-color: #2f6986 !important;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 1px #10374b, 0px 1px 1px #1f4e66, 2px 1px 1px #10374b, 1px 2px 1px #1f4e66, 3px 2px 1px #10374b, 2px 3px 1px #1f4e66, 4px 3px 1px #10374b, 3px 4px 1px #1f4e66, 5px 4px 1px #10374b, 4px 5px 1px #1f4e66, 6px 5px 1px #10374b !important;
}

.why2:hover {
  background-color: #1a5573 !important;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in !important;
  color: #ffffffeb !important;
}

.f2 {
  color: #6cff53ba !important;
  margin: 1%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#buttonstart {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #6AB1D4;
  margin: 0;
}

#mathbox {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: #e8e8e854;
  display: none;
  top: 10vh;
  position: relative;
}

#resultado {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 5vh;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid #7e7e98b0;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #4ea4ce;
}

#demo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -1rem;
}

#circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ffffff33;
  width: 3.3rem;
  height: 3.3rem;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#circle {
  border: 1rem solid #ffffff33;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 1rem solid #ffffff69;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#operaciones {
  margin: auto;
  width: 45vw;
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: #3b86ab69;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  border: 1px solid #3f95bf;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.op {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3rem;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#operador {
  margin: 0 1.5rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#atr54 {
  position: relative;
  width: 45vw;
  height: 30vh;
}

#submit2 {
  display: none;
}

.retry {
  background-color: #2f6986 !important;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 1px #10374b, 0px 1px 1px #1f4e66, 2px 1px 1px #10374b, 1px 2px 1px #1f4e66, 3px 2px 1px #10374b, 2px 3px 1px #1f4e66, 4px 3px 1px #10374b, 3px 4px 1px #1f4e66, 5px 4px 1px #10374b, 4px 5px 1px #1f4e66, 6px 5px 1px #10374b !important;
  display: none
}

.f6 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

#retryid {
  border: 0;
  background-color: #9c43ccdb;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in;
  bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 2%;
  color: #ffffffeb;
}

#retryid {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
  padding: 0 5%;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 1px #2e134dc9, 0px 1px 1px #7a34cac9, 2px 1px 1px #2e134dc9, 1px 2px 1px #7a34cac9, 3px 2px 1px #2e134dc9, 2px 3px 1px #7a34cac9, 4px 3px 1px #2e134dc9, 3px 4px 1px #7a34cac9, 5px 4px 1px #2e134dc9, 4px 5px 1px #7a34cac9, 6px 5px 1px #2e134dc9;
  background-color: #7a34cac9;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#retryid:hover {
  background-color: #1a5573 !important;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in !important;
  color: #ffffffeb !important;
}

.why3 {
  background-color: #7a3fbd !important;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 1px #4c1e80, 0px 1px 1px #642ca5, 2px 1px 1px #4c1e80, 1px 2px 1px #642ca5, 3px 2px 1px #4c1e80, 2px 3px 1px #642ca5, 4px 3px 1px #4c1e80, 3px 4px 1px #1f4e66, 5px 4px 1px #4c1e80, 4px 5px 1px #642ca5, 6px 5px 1px #4c1e80 !important;
}

.why3:hover {
  background-color: #581d9b !important;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in !important;
  color: #ffffffeb !important;
}

#score2,
f7 {
  font-size: 2rem !important;
  display: block !important;
}

#tittle6 {
  position: relative;
  top: 4%;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 3px 4px 2px #00000082;
}

.escondido {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #2d97cb;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  height: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

#Result {
  display: none;
  background-color: #6ab1d4;
  border: 0;
}

#resultbody {
  background-color: #4ea4ce;
  text-align: center;
}

.mes {
  color: white;
  font-size: 4rem;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 3px 4px 2px #00000082;
}

.mes:first-child {
  color: white;
  font-size: 4rem;
  margin-bottom: 5% !important;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 3px 4px 2px #00000082;
}

.mess {
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-shadow: 3px 4px 2px #00000082;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #00000082;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  text-transform: capitalize !important;
}

#retryid2 {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
  padding: 0 5%;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 1px #2e134dc9, 0px 1px 1px #7a34cac9, 2px 1px 1px #2e134dc9, 1px 2px 1px #7a34cac9, 3px 2px 1px #2e134dc9, 2px 3px 1px #7a34cac9, 4px 3px 1px #2e134dc9, 3px 4px 1px #7a34cac9, 5px 4px 1px #2e134dc9, 4px 5px 1px #7a34cac9, 6px 5px 1px #2e134dc9;
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block !important;
  background-color: #7a34cac9;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#retryid2:hover {
  background-color: #1a5573 !important;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in !important;
  border: 0;
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
  color: #ffffffeb !important;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.atr234 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-shadow: 3px 4px 2px #00000082;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #00000082;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

#formresults {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="background">
  <h1 id="tittle" class="f1">Test</h1>
  <div id="atr">
    <h1 id="tittle2" class="f1 f2">math</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="atr" class="ahke">
    <button id="buttonstart">
        <a id="why" class="why2" href="#">Start</a>
      </button>

    <div id="mathbox">
      <div id="operaciones">
        <div id="atr54">

          <div class="op" id="num1"></div>

          <div class="op" id="operador"></div>
          <div class="op" id="num2"></div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <input id="resultado" type="number" placeholder="Answer">
```