# Change selectbox placeholder font-weight

Tags: html, css

Is possible to change **select box placeholder font-weight** via **CSS** only?
I was trying to change it on different browser's with different webkit's prefixes and stil can't find a solution. 
*I have only **CSS** access.*

What i'm trying to achieve (*only font-weight*)

From:

[image]

To:

[image]

**CSS:**

```
.form > div.Content.ui-widget-content.ui-tabs-panel.PassengerDetailsTableBack > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div.fn_birthdate > div > div.col-xs-3 > select::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.form > div.Content.ui-widget-content.ui-tabs-panel.PassengerDetailsTableBack > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div.fn_birthdate > div > div.col-xs-3 > select::-moz-placeholder,
.form > div.Content.ui-widget-content.ui-tabs-panel.PassengerDetailsTableBack > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div.fn_birthdate > div > div.col-xs-3 > select:-ms-input-placeholder,
.form > div.Content.ui-widget-content.ui-tabs-panel.PassengerDetailsTableBack > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div.fn_birthdate > div > div.col-xs-3 > select:-o-input-placeholder{
    font-weight: 400!important;
}
```

Comment: Yes i'm targeting it correctly, and it's not overriden. These prefixed worked for me on normal input fields, but never on select inputs.

Comment: You should not combine vendor-specific CSS pseudo-elements. According to CSS documentation. Maybe thats the issue. This post should give you more info -> [Click here to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982449/why-isnt-it-possible-to-combine-vendor-specific-pseudo-elements-classes-into-on)

Comment: Can you add your HTML please!

Comment: @nourza Sorry, can't add HTML because I was targeting this element via DOM. I have only CSS access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { font-weight: 400!important; }
::-moz-placeholder { font-weight: 400!important; } /* firefox 19+ */
:-ms-input-placeholder { font-weight: 400!important; } /* ie */
input:-moz-placeholder {font-weight: 400!important; }
```

Try this and let me know whats the result

Comment: This overrides every single placeholder but at least works.