# Footer elements not floating

Tags: css, html, flexbox, css-float

What I am trying to create, is a footer with the contact and social media underneath it with the copyright on the opposite side of the footer. Here is an image of what I'm trying to accomplish. [image: footer goal] If it looks like my code is incomplete, that is because I am coding the media query for the desktop version.

```css
/*! HTML5 Boilerplate v6.1.0 | MIT License | https://html5boilerplate.com/ */

/*
 * What follows is the result of much research on cross-browser styling.
 * Credit left inline and big thanks to Nicolas Gallagher, Jonathan Neal,
 * Kroc Camen, and the H5BP dev community and team.
 */

/* ==========================================================================
   Base styles: opinionated defaults
   ========================================================================== */

html {
    color: #222;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

/*
 * Remove text-shadow in selection highlight:
 * https://twitter.com/miketaylr/status/12228805301
 *
 * Vendor-prefixed and regular ::selection selectors cannot be combined:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/16982510/7133471
 *
 * Customize the background color to match your design.
 */

::-moz-selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

/*
 * A better looking default horizontal rule
 */

hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*
 * Remove the gap between audio, canvas, iframes,
 * images, videos and the bottom of their containers:
 * https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/440
 */

audio,
canvas,
iframe,
img,
svg,
video {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/*
 * Remove default fieldset styles.
 */

fieldset {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*
 * Allow only vertical resizing of textareas.
 */

textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Browser Upgrade Prompt
   ========================================================================== */

.browserupgrade {
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Author's custom styles
   ========================================================================== */

   /* General Styles */

   html {
    font-size: 16px;
   }

   body {
     font-size: 1em;
     font-family: 'Myriad Pro';
     color: #000000;
     text-align: left;
   }

   ul, li {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
   }

   a {
     color: #ffffff;
     text-decoration: none;
   }

   p {
     font-size: .875em;
     line-height: 1.285;
   }

   header figure a img {
     width: 100%;
   }

   nav img {
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
   }

   .content-wrapper {
     width: 100%;
   }

   /* -------------------- Base Header - Footer Styles -------------------- */

   header, footer {
     background-color: #e229a3;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     flex-flow: row wrap;
   }

   header {
     padding: 15px 0;
   }

   header .content-wrapper {
     margin: 0;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     flex-flow: row wrap;
   }

   header figure {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     flex-flow: row wrap;
   }

   .header-divider {
     background: #a8eb6c;
     height: 3px;
     width: 100%;
     margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
   }

   header nav {
     width: 50%;
     font-size: 2.125em;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-around;
     align-items: center;
     flex-flow: row wrap;
   }

   header nav ul {
     width: 100%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-around;
   }

   header nav ul li {
     font-size: 1.125em;
   }

   footer {
     text-align: center;
     flex-direction: column;
     color: #ffffff;
   }

   footer p {
     margin: 0;
   }

   footer .content-wrapper {
     width: 15%;
     margin: 10px 0;
   }

   footer .content-wrapper h4 {
     font-family: 'Myriad pro';
     font-size: 2.125em;
     font-weight: lighter;
     text-align: center;
   }

   footer .social-icons {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: center;
   }

   footer .social-icons p {
     background-color: #a8eb6c;
     border-radius: 50%;
     width: 70px;
     height: 70px;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
   }

   footer .social-icons p i {
     font-size: 2.125em;
   }

   .footer .social {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: center;
   }

   footer .copyright {
     margin: 20px 0;
     font-size: 2.125em;
   }

   /* -------------------- Mobile Styles - Homepage -------------------- */

   main .content-wrapper {
     text-align: center;
     align-items: center;
   }

   main h1 {
     font-style: italic;
     font-size: 50px;
     text-align: center;
     margin: 60px 0 60px 60px;
   }

   main figure img {
     border: 10px solid #a8eb6c;
     margin: 0 16px 0 0;
     width: 500px;
     height: 500px;
     margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
   }

   main figure button {
     background-color: #a8eb6c;
     margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
     align-items: center;
     font-family: 'Myriad Pro';
     font-size: 2.125em;
   }

   main figure figcaption {
     margin: 30px 0 0 0;
     align-items: center;
     font-family: 'Myriad Pro';
     font-size: 2em;
   }

/* ==========================================================================
   Helper classes
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Hide visually and from screen readers
 */

.hidden {
    display: none !important;
}

/*
 * Hide only visually, but have it available for screen readers:
 * https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/hiding-content-for-accessibility
 *
 * 1. For long content, line feeds are not interpreted as spaces and small width
 *    causes content to wrap 1 word per line:
 *    https://medium.com/@jessebeach/beware-smushed-off-screen-accessible-text-5952a4c2cbfe
 */

.visuallyhidden {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap; /* 1 */
}

/*
 * Extends the .visuallyhidden class to allow the element
 * to be focusable when navigated to via the keyboard:
 * https://www.drupal.org/node/897638
 */

.visuallyhidden.focusable:active,
.visuallyhidden.focusable:focus {
    clip: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: static;
    width: auto;
    white-space: inherit;
}

/*
 * Hide visually and from screen readers, but maintain layout
 */

.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}

/*
 * Clearfix: contain floats
 *
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    `contenteditable` attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that receive the `clearfix` class.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   EXAMPLE Media Queries for Responsive Design.
   These examples override the primary ('mobile first') styles.
   Modify as content requires.
   ========================================================================== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

  /* General styles */
  .content-wrapper {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 100px 0;
  }

  /* Header */
  header {
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 40%;
  }

  header .content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  header figure {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
  }

  header nav {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    padding: 60px;
    font-size: 1.125em;
  }

  header nav ul {
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-right: 60px;
  }

  .header-divider {
    display: none;
  }

  /* Main */

  main h1 {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 60px 0 60px 0;
  }

  main figure {
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
  }

  figure {
    margin: 1em 20px;
  }

  main figure img {
    border: 10px solid #a8eb6c;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  }

  main figure figcaption {
    font-size: 1.125em;
  }

  main figure button {
    background-color: #a8eb6c;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    font-family: 'Myriad pro';
  }

  footer {
      background-color: #e229a3;
      background-size: 50% 100%;
      clear: both;
    }

    footer .content-wrapper {
      width: 50%;
      font-size: 1.125em;
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
    }

    footer .content-wrapper h4 {
      color: #000000;
      font-size: 1.125em;
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 150px;
    }

    footer a {
      color: #000000;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    footer .social-icons {
      padding: 0 150px 0 15px;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      margin:
    }

    footer .social-icons p {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    }

    footer .social-icons p i {
      font-size: 1.125em;
    }

    footer .copyright {
      font-size: 1.125em;
      width: 50%;
      text-align:left;
      padding-left: 150px;
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;

    }
}

@media print,
       (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
       (min-resolution: 1.25dppx),
       (min-resolution: 120dpi) {
    /* Style adjustments for high resolution devices */
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Print styles.
   Inlined to avoid the additional HTTP request:
   https://www.phpied.com/delay-loading-your-print-css/
   ========================================================================== */

@media print {
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
        background: transparent !important;
        color: #000 !important; /* Black prints faster */
        -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
    }

    a,
    a:visited {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    a[href]:after {
        content: " (" attr(href) ")";
    }

    abbr[title]:after {
        content: " (" attr(title) ")";
    }

    /*
     * Don't show links that are fragment identifiers,
     * or use the `javascript:` pseudo protocol
     */

    a[href^="#"]:after,
    a[href^="javascript:"]:after {
        content: "";
    }

    pre {
        white-space: pre-wrap !important;
    }
    pre,
    blockquote {
        border: 1px solid #999;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    /*
     * Printing Tables:
     * http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Printing_Tables
     */

    thead {
        display: table-header-group;
    }

    tr,
    img {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    p,
    h2,
    h3 {
        orphans: 3;
        widows: 3;
    }

    h2,
    h3 {
        page-break-after: avoid;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Art Attack</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="about/index.html">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="contact/index.html">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="shopping/index.html">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <figure>
          <a href="index.html" role="link"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="art-attack-logo"></a>
        </figure>
        <div class="header-divider"></div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="contact/index.html" target="_blank" role="link">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="about/index.html" target="_blank" role="link">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="shopping/index.html" target="_blank" role="link"></a><img src="img/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart">
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <main>
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <h1>"Creativity is the fuel for something amazing!"</h1>
        <figure>
          <img src="img/drawstring-bag.jpg" alt="drawstring-bag">
          <figcaption>Purses • Tops • Skirts</figcaption>
          <button role="button">Sensational Sewing</button>
        </figure>

        <figure>
          <img src="img/charm-necklace.jpg" alt="icecream-necklace">
          <figcaption>Earrings • Pendants • Clay Necklaces</figcaption>
          <button role="button">Creative Charms</button>
        </figure>

        <figure>
          <img src="img/phone-case.jpg" alt="phone-case">
          <figcaption>Scarves • Mittens • Plushies</figcaption>
          <button role="button">Knockout Knitting</button>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
      <div class="content-wrapper">
          <h4>Contact</h4>
            <div class="social-icons">
              <p>
                <a href="mailto:GracieArtAttack@gmail.com"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a>
              </p>
              <p>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/artsbygracie/?hl=en" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
      <div class="copyright">
        <p>Copyright 2018 | Art Attacked</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
<html>
```

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You should provide a [mcve], we do not want to parse through all your code.

Comment: OP earlier provided minimal code, but was not able to solve using the answers below, so the full code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easy doing this with a flexbox:

1. Make `footer` a flexbox and give `align-items: center` to center them vertically.
2. Make your `content-wrapper` a *column* flexbox and align the `h4` and `social-icons` one below the other.
3. `social-icons` can also be a flexbox to put the icons in a row rather than one below the other.

See demo below:

```css
footer {
  background-color: #e229a3;
  background-size: 50% 100%;
  display: flex; /* define a flexbox */
  flex-direction: row-reverse; /* reverse the items */
  align-items: center; /* align to the center */
}

footer .content-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  display: flex; /* define a flexbox */
  flex-direction: column; /* column flexbox */
  align-items: flex-end; /* align to the end horizontally*/
  padding-right: 25px;
}

footer .content-wrapper h4 {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

footer a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer .social-icons {
  display: flex; /* define a flexbox */
}

footer .social-icons p {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

footer .social-icons p i {
  font-size: 1.125em;
}

footer .copyright {
  font-size: 1.125em;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<footer>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <h4>Contact</h4>
    <div class="social-icons">
      <p>
        <a href="mailto:GracieArtAttack@gmail.com"><i class="fa fas fa-envelope"></i></a>
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/skillcrush/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="copyright">
    <p>Copyright 2018 | Unplugged</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

---

I commented `width: 100%` and `width: 15%` first of all to *fix the stretching of the social icons* in the mobile version. The desktop version was fixed using these changes:

```
footer {
    background-color: #e229a3;
    background-size: 50% 100%;
    clear: both;
    display: flex; /* ADDED */
    flex-direction: row-reverse; /* ADDED */
    align-items: center; /* ADDED */
}
footer .content-wrapper {
    /*width: 50%;*/
    width: auto; /* ADDED */
    font-size: 1.125em;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

See demo below:

```css
/*! HTML5 Boilerplate v6.1.0 | MIT License | https://html5boilerplate.com/ */


/*
 * What follows is the result of much research on cross-browser styling.
 * Credit left inline and big thanks to Nicolas Gallagher, Jonathan Neal,
 * Kroc Camen, and the H5BP dev community and team.
 */


/* ==========================================================================
   Base styles: opinionated defaults
   ========================================================================== */

html {
  color: #222;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.4;
}


/*
 * Remove text-shadow in selection highlight:
 * https://twitter.com/miketaylr/status/12228805301
 *
 * Vendor-prefixed and regular ::selection selectors cannot be combined:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/16982510/7133471
 *
 * Customize the background color to match your design.
 */

::-moz-selection {
  background: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
  background: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}


/*
 * A better looking default horizontal rule
 */

hr {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*
 * Remove the gap between audio, canvas, iframes,
 * images, videos and the bottom of their containers:
 * https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/440
 */

audio,
canvas,
iframe,
img,
svg,
video {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/*
 * Remove default fieldset styles.
 */

fieldset {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*
 * Allow only vertical resizing of textareas.
 */

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}


/* ==========================================================================
   Browser Upgrade Prompt
   ========================================================================== */

.browserupgrade {
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0.2em 0;
}


/* ==========================================================================
   Author's custom styles
   ========================================================================== */


/* General Styles */

html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro';
  color: #000000;
  text-align: left;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  font-size: .875em;
  line-height: 1.285;
}

header figure a img {
  width: 100%;
}

nav img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.content-wrapper {
  /*width: 100%;*/
}


/* -------------------- Base Header - Footer Styles -------------------- */

header,
footer {
  background-color: #e229a3;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

header {
  padding: 15px 0;
}

header .content-wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

header figure {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.header-divider {
  background: #a8eb6c;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
}

header nav {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 2.125em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

header nav ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

header nav ul li {
  font-size: 1.125em;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #ffffff;
}

footer p {
  margin: 0;
}

footer .content-wrapper {
  /*width: 15%;*/
  margin: 10px 0;
}

footer .content-wrapper h4 {
  font-family: 'Myriad pro';
  font-size: 2.125em;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
}

footer .social-icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

footer .social-icons p {
  background-color: #a8eb6c;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

footer .social-icons p i {
  font-size: 2.125em;
}

.footer .social {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

footer .copyright {
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-size: 2.125em;
}


/* -------------------- Mobile Styles - Homepage -------------------- */

main .content-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

main h1 {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 60px 0 60px 60px;
}

main figure img {
  border: 10px solid #a8eb6c;
  margin: 0 16px 0 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

main figure button {
  background-color: #a8eb6c;
  margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro';
  font-size: 2.125em;
}

main figure figcaption {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro';
  font-size: 2em;
}


/* ==========================================================================
   Helper classes
   ========================================================================== */


/*
 * Hide visually and from screen readers
 */

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}


/*
 * Hide only visually, but have it available for screen readers:
 * https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/hiding-content-for-accessibility
 *
 * 1. For long content, line feeds are not interpreted as spaces and small width
 *    causes content to wrap 1 word per line:
 *    https://medium.com/@jessebeach/beware-smushed-off-screen-accessible-text-5952a4c2cbfe
 */

.visuallyhidden {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* 1 */
}


/*
 * Extends the .visuallyhidden class to allow the element
 * to be focusable when navigated to via the keyboard:
 * https://www.drupal.org/node/897638
 */

.visuallyhidden.focusable:active,
.visuallyhidden.focusable:focus {
  clip: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  position: static;
  width: auto;
  white-space: inherit;
}


/*
 * Hide visually and from screen readers, but maintain layout
 */

.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}


/*
 * Clearfix: contain floats
 *
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    `contenteditable` attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that receive the `clearfix` class.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  /* 1 */
  display: table;
  /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}


/* ==========================================================================
   EXAMPLE Media Queries for Responsive Design.
   These examples override the primary ('mobile first') styles.
   Modify as content requires.
   ========================================================================== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  /* General styles */
  .content-wrapper {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 100px 0;
  }
  /* Header */
  header {
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 40%;
  }
  header .content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  header figure {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
  }
  header nav {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    padding: 60px;
    font-size: 1.125em;
  }
  header nav ul {
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-right: 60px;
  }
  .header-divider {
    display: none;
  }
  /* Main */
  main h1 {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 60px 0 60px 0;
  }
  main figure {
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
  }
  figure {
    margin: 1em 20px;
  }
  main figure img {
    border: 10px solid #a8eb6c;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  }
  main figure figcaption {
    font-size: 1.125em;
  }
  main figure button {
    background-color: #a8eb6c;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    font-family: 'Myriad pro';
  }
  footer {
    background-color: #e229a3;
    background-size: 50% 100%;
    clear: both;
    display: flex; /* ADDED */
    flex-direction: row-reverse; /* ADDED */
    align-items: center; /* ADDED */
  }
  footer .content-wrapper {
    /*width: 50%;*/
    width: auto; /* ADDED */
    font-size: 1.125em;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
  }
  footer .content-wrapper h4 {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 150px;
  }
  footer a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  footer .social-icons {
    padding: 0 150px 0 15px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin:
  }
  footer .social-icons p {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  }
  footer .social-icons p i {
    font-size: 1.125em;
  }
  footer .copyright {
    font-size: 1.125em;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
  }
}

@media print,
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
(min-resolution: 1.25dppx),
(min-resolution: 120dpi) {
  /* Style adjustments for high resolution devices */
}


/* ==========================================================================
   Print styles.
   Inlined to avoid the additional HTTP request:
   https://www.phpied.com/delay-loading-your-print-css/
   ========================================================================== */

@media print {
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    background: transparent !important;
    color: #000 !important;
    /* Black prints faster */
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
  }
  a,
  a:visited {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  a[href]:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ")";
  }
  abbr[title]:after {
    content: " (" attr(title) ")";
  }
  /*
     * Don't show links that are fragment identifiers,
     * or use the `javascript:` pseudo protocol
     */
  a[href^="#"]:after,
  a[href^="javascript:"]:after {
    content: "";
  }
  pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap !important;
  }
  pre,
  blockquote {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
  /*
     * Printing Tables:
     * http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Printing_Tables
     */
  thead {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
  tr,
  img {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
  p,
  h2,
  h3 {
    orphans: 3;
    widows: 3;
  }
  h2,
  h3 {
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Art Attack</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="about/index.html">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="contact/index.html">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="shopping/index.html">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <figure>
        <a href="index.html" role="link"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="art-attack-logo"></a>
      </figure>
      <div class="header-divider"></div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="contact/index.html" target="_blank" role="link">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="about/index.html" target="_blank" role="link">About</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="shopping/index.html" target="_blank" role="link"></a><img src="img/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart">
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <h1>"Creativity is the fuel for something amazing!"</h1>
      <figure>
        <img src="img/drawstring-bag.jpg" alt="drawstring-bag">
        <figcaption>Purses • Tops • Skirts</figcaption>
        <button role="button">Sensational Sewing</button>
      </figure>

      <figure>
        <img src="img/charm-necklace.jpg" alt="icecream-necklace">
        <figcaption>Earrings • Pendants • Clay Necklaces</figcaption>
        <button role="button">Creative Charms</button>
      </figure>

      <figure>
        <img src="img/phone-case.jpg" alt="phone-case">
        <figcaption>Scarves • Mittens • Plushies</figcaption>
        <button role="button">Knockout Knitting</button>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <h4>Contact</h4>
      <div class="social-icons">
        <p>
          <a href="mailto:GracieArtAttack@gmail.com"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a>
        </p>
        <p>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/artsbygracie/?hl=en" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="copyright">
      <p>Copyright 2018 | Art Attacked</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: maybe you can add the full code for us to look into it, not reproducible with code in the question

Comment: I tried and what happens is instead of showing the desktop version (the one I am having issues with) it shows the mobile version which is fine.

Comment: Would you like to see my entire code or my other footer code for the mobile device?

Comment: Entire code would be good so that we can understand what's going on :)

Comment: I just added the entire code, thank you so much for helping. I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: one more question, so the mobile version is fine in the code that you have added, but the desktop version need to be fixed right?

Comment: So what I was doing is I coded the mobile version first. Had no trouble with that but then when I put in a media query for the desktop version and was coding that, everything was working great until the footer content wouldn’t float. I sorta got it but the copyright wouldn’t line up.

Comment: @kukkuz Do not tell OP to post **all** their code, a [mcve] is what we want. If at all provide the _full code_, an external link, as e.g. a fiddle or similar, could be okay.

Comment: @kukkuz It worked! Thanks so much! I greatly appreciate it. I understand where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking in the right way, hopefully the following code will help. You could introduce a media query, but the following version is responsive all the way.

```css
footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e229a3;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

footer .content-wrapper {
  width: 30%;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

footer .content-wrapper p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 40px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

footer a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer .social-icons {
  padding: 0 30px 10px 0;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  float: right;
}

footer .social-icons p {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 0 0 18px;
}

footer .social-icons p i {
  font-size: 1.125em;
}

footer .copyright {
  font-size: 1.125em;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin: 9px 0;
}

footer .copyright p {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

footer .social-icons div {
  min-height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<p>Hi Silk, I think this might be what you're looking for </p>


<footer>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <p>Contact</p>
    <div class="social-icons">
      <div>
        <a href="mailto:GracieArtAttack@gmail.com"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/skillcrush/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="copyright">
    <p>Copyright 2018 | Unplugged</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! What was I doing wrong? For some reason, when I try to use this code, it messes up the code I have. I think it's because you have the footer as fixed. What I meant by media query is that I am coding a media query for the website because I coded mobile first.

Comment: what do you mean by messes up the code? can you share a screenshot? this is also mobile first, the copyright part is 70% of the width, the rest is 30%... this way we can avoid the media queries

Comment: How can I share a screenshot?

Comment: I updated the question with my entire code and the screenshot you requested. Thank you so much for helping me. I greatly appreciate it.