# Why selector "input:read-only, input:-moz-read-only" won't work on Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

Why selector `input:read-only, input:-moz-read-only` won't work on Google Chrome? Works only, if I write it as two separate selectors `input:read-only`, `input:-moz-read-only` with same instruction.

```css
input:read-only,
input:-moz-read-only {
  border: 1px solid red;
}


/* Works if i will repeat it separate, like below */


/* input:read-only {
    border: 1px solid red;
} */
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" value="Read-only" id="" readonly>
```

Comment: Note that Firefox doesn't need the `-moz-` prefix

Comment: And you can't combine vendor prefixed selectors. Separate them.

Comment: Thanks for comments, you are right. Btw I asked about it, because [mdn site about :read-only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:read-only#confirming_form_information_in_read-onlyread-write_controls) shows this selector as an example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @Paulie_D said, "... you can't combine vendor prefixed selectors. Separate them.".
Similar question was already [answered on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982449/why-isnt-it-possible-to-combine-vendor-specific-pseudo-elements-classes-into-on).
I close the question.