# Grouping placeholder color styling

Tags: html, css

How come this works:

```
input { color: #807E82; }
input:-moz-placeholder { color: #807E82; }
input::-moz-placeholder { color: #807E82; }
input:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #807E82; }
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #807E82; }
```

But this doesn't:

```
input,
input:-moz-placeholder,
input::-moz-placeholder,
input:-ms-input-placeholder,
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #807E82; }
```

Seems a bit of a pain if I want to change all the input colors and placeholder colors on the quickly.

Comment: did you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css

Comment: Ah no I didn't find that in my searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because how [**CSS error handling works**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#Conformance): if a single rule in a selector is invalid (not recognized by a user agent, to be precise), the whole selector and its rule is discarded by a user agent.

In the second example, each browser will have its own indigestible part of the selector (Firefox won't know anything about `-ms-input...`, Chrome and IE - about `-moz-...` etc). So the whole rule will be ignored.

Comment: Aaah right I never knew that. Seems crazy the browser can't understand what is relevant to it? It can differentiate between vendor prefixes like -moz -webkit etc. so why not this? Fair enough though, if that's the rules then that's it

Comment: @Cooper I'd suggest checking [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816764/what-is-the-rationale-behind-dropping-css-rules-with-an-invalid-selector) as well. In short, it's not as easy as it seems to make a distinction between 'wrong' and 'irrelevant' without breaking things both in past and in future. )