# Using LESS with vendor-specific pseudo selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

as I understand from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816764/invalid-css-selector-causes-rule-to-be-dropped-what-is-the-rationale/13831877#13831877), I can't place my CSS selectors which contains "pseudo browsers selectors" (`-moz-range-track`, `-webkit-slider-thumb`, and so on) separated by comma, because if browser did not recognize one of the selectors then will ignore all the rules in curly brackets {}.

So when I try to compile my LESS rules:

```
input {
&[type=range]{
    &::-moz-range-track,
    &::-webkit-slider-runnable-track
    {
      width:100%;
      height: 32px;
    }
  }
}
```

In the result I will see:

```
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track,
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
}
```

Which will not work because of reason I mentioned earlier.

So in LESS I have to do it like (it isn't of course LESS style):

```
input {
&[type=range]{
    &::-moz-range-track
    {
      width:100%;
      height: 32px;
    }
    &::-webkit-slider-runnable-track
    {
      width:100%;
      height: 32px;
    }
  }
}
```

Which compiles to:

```
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
}
```

And works as expected.

And my question, is there any possible to do it looks nicely in LESS?

Comment: I recommend lesshat mixin, works great for any vendor specific stuff: http://lesshat.madebysource.com

Comment: @seahorsepip Don't. (See [here](https://github.com/madebysource/lesshat/issues/162) why).

Comment: @seven-phases-max Thanks! Haven't used it for a while, didn't know that the project was abandoned :P

Comment: Thanks guys, that's the solution I was looking for.