# Is there an explanation for why we cannot place semicolons between CSS declaration blocks?

Tags: css, syntax

When you place semicolons between css rules, the rule following the semi colon will be ignored. This can lead to some [very strange results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1abI.png).  The MDN has a jsfiddle that can be used to show this effect rather clearly.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/e5wv3m0e/1/) is the initial state, and [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jpadw72x/1/) is after the first rule has a semicolon at its end.

Fortunately it is, essentially, [universal practice to exclude semicolons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Syntax) from between one's css blocks.

My question is: Why is this the case? I've heard that this is the case because it will save space (in this case, exactly one character per css rule). But this reasoning, while true, seems a tad strange. I couldn't find specifics on how much space each char in a css file occupies, but if it's analogous to JS, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219526/how-many-bytes-in-a-javascript-string) tells us that each char is approximately 16 bits, or 2 bytes.  Meaning we would save 2 bytes per rule.

According to [this list of average connection speed by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_Internet_connection_speeds) the global average connection speed is 5.1 Megabits/second. Since we save exactly 1 char per rule by not allowing semi-colons, and each char is 16 bits, we can show that on average the amount of rules it takes it takes us to save one second is:

```
5,100,000(bits/second) / 16(bits{saved}/rule) 

(5,100,000/16)*[(bits * rule)/(second * bits] or

318750 (rule/second)
```

And so based on the global average connection speed, it would require over 300,000 rules to save us one second of time.

Surely there must exist more efficient methods of saving download time for the user, and there does such as minification/uglification of css/js. Or the reduction of length of the names of CSS Properties, since these are much longer than 1 char and can appear many times, shortening these could save orders of magnitudes of more bytes when compared to chopping off a trailing semicolon.

More important than the bytes saved, in my opinion, is how confusing this can get for the developer. Many of us are trained by habit to follow closed braces with a semicolon.

```
returnType/functionDec functionName(arguments){
 //...function body
};
```

is a VERY common pattern found in a great many of languages (including JavaScript), and it is absolutely possible to imagine a developer typing

```
cssRuleA{ 
 /*style Rules */
};
cssRuleB{
 /* Style Rules*/
};
```

as an accidental result of this habit.  The console will log no errors, the developer will have no indication that a mistake has been made outside of styles not showing up correctly.  The absolutely WORST part of this, is that even though cssRuleA is what's causing the error, it will work just fine, cssRuleB will be the rule not displaying correctly *even if there is nothing wrong with it*.  The fact that

1. This logs no error in the console and
2. The style not displaying is never the style at fault in this situation

can especially cause issues in large projects where style/UI issues can have many different possible roots.

Does there exist some factor inherent in CSS that makes this convention make more sense? Is there something in some white papers I missed that explains why this is how CSS behaves?  Personally, I tried to see if it is faster to exclude semicolons from a perspective of [Finite Automata/Grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_grammar#Recognizing_ambiguous_grammars), but I couldn't definitively determine if it was faster or not.

Comment: *"Many of us are trained by habit to follow closed braces with a semicolon"* -- This is only the case for statements, not blocks, nor function declarations. I would call a style bug on the declaration `function foo() {};`, because the semicolon does not belong there. It's only allowed because JavaScript permits the empty statement -- if it did not, this would be a syntax error. Same with `if (foo) {};`. If you blindly put semicolons after every closing brace, you don't understand the JavaScript language grammar at all.

Comment: Just to clarify: semicolons terminate a statement. Function declarations *are not* statements. Blocks (if/else/for/while/etc.) *are not* statements.

Comment: I agree with you that you shouldn't put semicolons after every close brace, accidents do happen. More importantly is JS if you write ' if(true){
  console.log("do some stuff");
};
else{
  console.log("do some other stuff");}; '  the console WILL log an error, letting you know where you messed up, there's also clear reasons WHY that happens(eg: the if..else block is one statement and you shouldn't terminate it then try to continue).  My concern is that with this CSS feature is that it won't log an error and there isn't documentation (at least that i could find) to explain the behavior

Comment: *"the if..else block is one statement"* -- No, conditionals *are not* statements. Regarding CSS, I would expect browsers to log some kind of error parsing that CSS. The "documentation" you are seeking is the CSS grammar, which simply disallows semicolons to be used between rules. If you are having trouble with this problem in large projects, running lint tools against your JS and CSS source files should be automated and implemented immediately. A CSS lint tool will immediately tell you that your CSS is not valid.

Comment: And a JS lint tool will also tell you when you do incorrect things in JS (like place a semicolon after a function declaration).

Comment: Sorry for my slip of the tongue about statements, but I'd like to think my point still stands, regardless of my missuses of semantics. I fully understand that the reason I can't place semi colons in between rules is because that's what the grammar dictates.  I want to know WHY the grammar was constructed to do so.  I can't seem to find sufficient motivation for those who wrote the grammar to make that rule. As for console outputs, I have tested this on FF (dev), Chrome, and IE, none of which log any error or warning for this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a “why” question (described very verbosely), not a practical programming question. Besides, answers would be opinions and would not help in programming.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela: Perhaps this question would be better asked from the perspective of an implementer, and not an author. I can see how an answer to this question might benefit someone writing a CSS parser. (Not that it would attract opinionated answers any less, though...)

Comment: Opinions are in no way the only answers to this question.  The answer I already accepted was not based on at all.  This is a question asking if performance concerns were what motivated a particular syntax rule in CSS.  Nor does this question have no practical implications, I would say it's a rather practical matter if someone CANNOT get a style to show correctly and it's because they accidentally added a semicolon to the end of the previous CSS rule. In fact, I'd argue that the lack of console feedback from any major browser for the application of this issue makes it even more practical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In CSS, rules are defined by either blocks, or statements, but not both at the same time. A block is a chunk of code that is surrounded by a pair of curly braces. A statement is a chunk of code that ends with a semicolon.

An empty "rule" is not a valid CSS rule, because it cannot be parsed as either a [qualified rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#qualified-rule) or an [at-rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#at-rule). So it stands to reason that a lone `;` between two blocks is invalid, for the same reason that a block that doesn't contain a prelude (either a selector-list, or an at-keyword followed by an optional prelude) is invalid: because it cannot be parsed into anything meaningful.

Only at-rules may take the form of statements and therefore be terminated by a semicolon (examples include `@charset` and `@import`); qualified rules never do. So when a malformed rule is encountered, if the parser isn't already parsing an at-rule, then it is treated as a qualified rule and *everything* up to and including the next matching set of curly braces is consumed and discarded, including the semicolon. This is described succinctly in [section 2.2 of css-syntax-3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#error-handling) (it says the text is non-normative, but that's only because the normative rules are defined in the grammar itself).

And the reason error handling takes such an eager approach in CSS is mostly due to [selector error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816764/invalid-css-selector-causes-rule-to-be-dropped-what-is-the-rationale/13831877#13831877) — if it were conservative, browsers might end up inadvertently parsing the following rule as something completely unexpected. For example, if IE6, which doesn't understand `>`, were to ignore just the `p >` in `p > span {...}` and regard everything starting with `span` as valid, the rule would end up matching *any* `span` element in IE6, whilst matching only the appropriate subset of elements in supporting browsers. (In fact, a similar issue *does* exist in IE6 with [chained class selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes/3772305#3772305) — `.foo.bar` is treated as `.bar`.) You could think of this, therefore, not as liberal error handling, but conservative application of CSS rules. Better not to apply a rule when in doubt than apply it with unexpected results.

Whoever told you it was for performance reasons is just making it up.

Comment: @Joshua Shearer: Glad I could help. To be honest, I was half expecting you to follow up with "why can't CSS just define empty rules to be valid, like empty statements are in JS?" That's something I think only the language designers can answer.

Comment: No, I feel that your answer is absolutely sufficient. I was unaware of how CSS handled invalid blocks. Still, to be honest, l would like to ask one of the language devs about this, but there's probably a snowballs chance of that happening.

Comment: @Joshua Shearer: On SO, yeah. Most of the CSSWG's public correspondence happens in the www-style@w3.org list - you'll have better luck there.