# CSS select multiple descendants of another element

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to select multiple elements that have an ancestor of a certain class, id, etc in CSS? e.g:

```
table.exams caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td
```

If not, is there a way to select all descendants of that element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now do this with [:is()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) selector. If it requires larger selection, you can exclude the smaller ratio using `:not` as a combination with it as in the code snippet:

This selector can be used in latest versions of all the 4 major browsers (Edge, Firefox, Chrome and Safari): https://caniuse.com/?search=is as on 26/1/2021.

```css
.match-elements :is(.match-1,.match-2,.match-5,.match-10) {
  background: #5548B0;
}

.match-elements :not(:is(.match-1,.match-2,.match-5,.match-10)) {
  background: #BADA55;
}

/* For snippet styling, not required */

.match-elements div {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="match-elements">
  <div class="match-1">Matched using is</div>
  <div class="match-2">Matched using is</div>
  <div class="match-3">Matched using not</div>
  <div class="match-4">Matched using not</div>
  <div class="match-5">Matched using is</div>
  <div class="match-6">Matched using not</div>
  <div class="match-7">Matched using not</div>
  <div class="match-8">Matched using not</div>
  <div class="match-9">Matched using not</div>
  <div class="match-10">Matched using is</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 36):

> Is it possible to select multiple elements that have an ancestor of a certain class, id, etc in CSS?

This is now possible with the [`:is()` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#matches), originating as `:matches()` mentioned in the original version of this answer below. Be sure not to get it mixed up with [`:where()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#zero-matches), which removes specificity that's otherwise critical to your selector:

```
table.exams :is(caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td)
```

---

Prior to `:is()`, this was not possible without duplicating the entire ancestor selector and specifying all of the descendants<sup>1</sup>:

```
table.exams caption, 
table.exams tbody, 
table.exams tfoot, 
table.exams thead, 
table.exams tr, 
table.exams th, 
table.exams td
```

It was only until late after Selectors 3 was being finalized that they proposed a pseudo-class notation to do this, and it was only recently that basic implementations have started showing up. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800779/why-cant-you-group-descendants-in-a-css-selector/11786102#11786102) for a little history lesson.

In short, the pseudo-class that's now entered the standard is known as `:matches()`. In the distant future, once browsers start implementing `:matches()`, you will be able to do something like this:

```
table.exams :matches(caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Specifically with tables, you can get away with `table.exams > :not(colgroup), table.exams > * > tr > *`, but as you can tell this is incredibly cryptic (not to mention it assumes you have no [script-supporting elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#script-supporting-elements-2) or nested tables within this table) and you're better off just listing all the descendants you want explicitly.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible to select multiple tags that have an ancestor of a certain class in CSS?

It is possible to use SCSS to achieve a result similar to :matches, as shown in [this article](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/m/matches/)

Also, certain browsers have partial support for `:matches` with vendor specific prefix.