# Using :not(:not()) to emulate (the hypothetical) :is() selector in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I would like to write jQuery statements like:

```
$(".someparentcontainer input[type=checkbox]:is(.foo, .bar, .xyz)")
```

As a shorthand for:

```
$(".someparentcontainer input[type=checkbox].foo, .someparentcontainer input[type=checkbox].bar, .someparentcontainer input[type=checkbox].xyz)")
```

Since jQuery doesn't support (to my knowledge) an :is() selector I came up with the following workaround:

```
$(".someparentcontainer input[type=checkbox]:not(:not(.foo, .bar, .xyz))")
```

I do realize that it has its drawbacks in terms of performance if .someparentcontainer has a ton of child elements, but it works pretty well for small dom-trees.

Are there any pitfalls I might be missing here? Any scenarios where this technique might fail?

Comment: You could create your own pseudo selector: https://jsfiddle.net/mLn1wbej/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any pitfalls I might be missing here? Any scenarios where this technique might fail?

As you've tagged your question [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors), [the standard does not allow `:not()` to be nested within another `:not()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation). Every known implementation of `:not()` in the standard correctly treats what you have as invalid. If jQuery allows this (I can't say I'm surprised if it does), then this is non-standard and you need to be very careful not to rely on it outside of jQuery (for example, it won't work in `querySelectorAll()`, or in CSS).

The *recommended* way to do this is to use `.filter()` instead:

```
// If you know that the element with any of these ids is always a checkbox,
// substitute ".someparentcontainer *" for the second selector string
$(".someparentcontainer input[type=checkbox]").filter(".foo, .bar, .xyz")
```

But this means you have to write two separate selector strings. Then again, there's no way to do this with a single standards-compliant complex selector until Selectors 4's `:matches()` is implemented anyway (see [Does jQuery have something like the :any or :matches pseudo-class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339353/does-jquery-have-something-like-the-any-or-matches-pseudo-class)).

Comment: I guess your answer sums up the one landmine that people should keep an eye out for. So I will accept it as the answer. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery's `find` function:

```js
$("#someparentcontainer").find("#foo, #bar, #xyz").css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someparentcontainer">
  <div id="foo">foo</div>
  <div id="bar">bar</div>
  <div id="abc">abc</div>
</div>
<div id="xyz">xyz</div>
```

Which makes much more sense.

Comment: +1 for the tip on find. Breaking the selector in two pieces would however pose some issues when/if utility functions are involved, if said functions  expect a unified selector. Things are bound to get harder if said utility functions are part of third party libraries. The .find() approach has its advantages but at a price similar to that of using :not(:not()). Feel free to tip me off in case I'm missing something.