# Is it right to list several elements within the same id separated by commas?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am wondering is it right to format CSS styles like this if link1,2,3 classes are within #cont id?

```
#cont .link1, .link2, .link3
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what to do -- both answers are clarifying)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you want to use:

```css
#cont .link1, #cont .link2, #cont .link3
```

Otherwise, only the first one will target elements with the class `link1` that are descendants of the element with the ID `cont`, while the last two will target **all** elements that have the class `link2` and `link3`.

Comment: No, this answer appeared 2 minutes later than epascarello's according to the stats

Comment: @user3695711 - No, that's two minutes *before*

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS Selectors Level 4 `:matches` or [`:any`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:any) in the near future

```
#cont:matches(.link1, .link2, .link3) {
  /* This is an experimental technology*/
}


#cont:-moz-any(.link1, .link2, .link3) {
  /* This is an experimental technology*/
}
```

Comment: Do not use `:any()`. Wait for `:matches()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800779/why-cant-you-group-descendants-in-a-css-selector/11786102#11786102

Comment: (There should probably be a descendant selector between the ID selector and the pseudo-class btw.)

Comment: Do any browsers support this yet?

Comment: @jo8691 Firefox and Chrome only  http://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/matches-any-pseudo-class/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is the same thing as

```css
#cont .link1 {}
.link2 {} 
.link3 {}
```

You are stuck with copying the selector over and over again.

```css
#cont .link1,
#cont .link2, 
#cont .link3 { }
```

There is no short cut in CSS to have nesting. [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) have that ability.

---

Example with Less would be

```less
#cont {
    .link1, .link2, .link3 {

    }
}
```