# How does the default user agent stylesheet style lists differently depending on their layout?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to create a custom style, and checking it with "HTML5 kitchen sink". The margin between nested <ul> elements confuses me.

When I inspect the elements: a <ul> has a top margin of 16px. A nested <ul> within a <ul> has a top margin of 0px. This leads me to believe that for the user agent there are not static defaults for each element as I used to believe, but a custom style sheet with a bunch of rules (e.g. testing for nested lists).

Question: How does the default user agent style the gap between nested <li> as zero, but between adjacent <li> items in side by side <ul> as NOT zero? Refer to below to make it more clear ("NO GAP BELOW HERE"/"GAP BELOW HERE"):

I created a code pen here: https://codepen.io/run_the_race/pen/JmqEER

```css
body {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
        <li>Unordered List item one
            <ul>
                <li>Nested list item, NO GAP BELOW HERE
                    <ul>
                        <li>Level 3, item one, NO GAP ABOVE HERE</li>
                        <li>Level 3, item two</li>
                        <li>Level 3, item three</li>
                        <li>Level 3, item four</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>List item two</li>
                <li>List item three</li>
                <li>List item four</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>List item two</li>
        <li>List item three</li>
        <li>List item four, GAP BELOW HERE</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>ul + ul: Item 1, GAP ABOVE HERE</li>
        <li>ul + ul: Il item 2</li>
        <li>ul + ul: Il item 2</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This leads me to believe that for the user agent there are not static defaults for each element as I used to believe, but a custom style sheet with a bunch of rules (e.g. testing for nested lists).

Yes, that's exactly the case. Every UA stylesheet contains defaults for a variety of situations. And many of these complex defaults are [standardized in the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#lists) along with the simple (by element type) ones, although each UA is of course free to customize (as you put it) its defaults.

In this case, the default `ul` and `ol` margins are simply zeroed out for any such elements that are nested. The UA doesn't apply any margins directly to `li` elements or perform any non-CSS special-casing logic. Here's how the HTML spec expresses it in terms of CSS:

```css
dir, dl, menu, ol, ul { margin-block-start: 1em; margin-block-end: 1em; }

:matches(dir, dl, menu, ol, ul) :matches(dir, dl, menu, ol, ul) {
  margin-block-start: 0; margin-block-end: 0;
}
```

Here's how Firefox does it:

```css
/* nested lists have no top/bottom margins */
:-moz-any(ul, ol, dir, menu, dl) ul,
:-moz-any(ul, ol, dir, menu, dl) ol,
:-moz-any(ul, ol, dir, menu, dl) dir,
:-moz-any(ul, ol, dir, menu, dl) menu,
:-moz-any(ul, ol, dir, menu, dl) dl {
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
}
```

And how Chrome does it:

```css
ol ul, ul ol, ul ul, ol ol {
    -webkit-margin-before: 0;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;
}
```

The only implementation differences are that Firefox continues to use its [experimental `:-moz-any()` pseudo-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800779/why-cant-you-group-descendants-in-a-css-selector/11786102#11786102), and Chrome hasn't implemented the standard [logical properties](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-logical-1) yet so it continues to use the non-standard `-webkit-margin-*` properties, and it only does this with `ul, ol` but not `dir, dl, menu`. But the principle is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed explanation, that is boss!

Comment: I'm keeping the code samples here for historical purposes, but note that :matches() has been turned into :is() and Chrome has shipped logical properties, so the HTML spec and the respective implementations have been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The agent simply applies margins to `ul` and then 0 margin to `ul ul`

Here's a Firefox example:

```css
ul {
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 1em;
}

:-moz-any(ul, ol, dir, menu, dl) ul {
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Unordered List item one
    <ul>
      <li>Nested list item, NO GAP BELOW HERE
        <ul>
          <li>Level 3, item one, NO GAP ABOVE HERE</li>
          <li>Level 3, item two</li>
          <li>Level 3, item three</li>
          <li>Level 3, item four</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
      <li>List item four</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>List item two</li>
  <li>List item three</li>
  <li>List item four, GAP BELOW HERE</li>
</ul>
```